# comma in definitions

Tags: punctuation, dictionaries

I'm wondering if the comma is used in definitions to separate a component of a definition from an alternative to that component. This is often done in German dictionaries, but I am not sure how things are done in English dictionaries. Note that I'm not talking about the standard sequence, "A, B, and C," where "A" and "B" are linked by a comma.

At the risk of going off-topic, a German example is as follows:

> erfolgreich hinter sich bringen, beenden
> (Translation: bring to an end, finish (something) successfully)

Here, "beenden" is presented as an alternative to "hinter sich bringen."

Comment: Sometimes a slash is used, as in "bring to an end / finish something".

Comment: There are no universally-observed orthographic conventions here. Merriam-Webster usually (but not *always*) uses a ***colon*** to separate alternative but closely-related definitions, but the full OED and many others use a ***semicolon***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm asking about whether commas are used to separate a component of a definition from an alternative to that component.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Let's say a definition is "free from anxiety **or** distress." Do you think English definitions could use a **comma** instead of "or" in it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or if a definition is "to allow yourself to be fully controlled **or** affected by (something, such as a strong emotion)," Do you think English definitions could use a **comma** instead of "or" in it?

Comment: "free from anxiety or distress" is a ***single*** definition, so no punctuation should "subdivide" it. An alternative definition might be written as **free from anxiety; free from distress**, but those two are so close I doubt any lexicographer would ever do so for that particular case.

Comment: German and English have different conventions for use of commas. Could you provide an example in English?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sure. In the following definition of "abolish,"  "or" cannot be replaced by a comma: 

to officially end or stop (something, such as a law)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that structure isn't normal in English dictionaries. While whole definitions might be separated by a comma, or more likely a colon or semicolon, each definition is written in a grammatically correct manner - which means alternatives are separated by 'or' or by a slash. For example, you might see 'abolish' defined in any of these ways:

"To end (something): to completely do away with."

"To stop or end (something)"

"To end/stop (something), usually in a formal context."

These examples didn't come from a specific dictionary, but represent formatting that would be normal.

It bears mentioning that if a reference *did* use the comma the way you asked, the audience would probably understand the meaning- but it would certainly be unusual.

Comment: Could you provide an actual example of how commas are used in definitions in the way you indicated? I suspect a difference between German and English definitions.

Comment: @Apollyon I don't have a specific example to give, no. I have seen it, but it's not common in reputable reference works. I don't understand what you mean by 'a difference between German and English definitions' - if you think it's a difference important enough to make my answer incorrect, please elaborate so I can examine the problem.

Comment: In the following English definition of "abolish," can "or" be replaced by a comma?

"to officially end **or** stop (something, such as a law)"

Comment: In a dictionary, yes, it could - though it would be a little awkward, the readers would understand the meaning. Outside of a reference work you couldn't do it that way, because the context wouldn't be clear enough to let the reader know.
The first two hits I got on google for define abolish were Merriam-Webster, which used colons: "to end the observance or effect of (something, such as a law) : to completely do away with (something)", and dictionary.com, which used semicolons: to do away with; put an end to; annul; make void. I'll change the answer to highlight that the usage would be unusual

Comment: The "abolish" example is different from the dictionary definitions you quoted.  In your examples, the colon or semicolon separates one self-contained alternative definition from another (E.g., "put an end to" and "annual" are self-contained alternatives.) On the other hand, in the "abolish" example, "stop (something such as a law) is not a self-contained alternative to "to officially end." The "or" is meant to say the definition is understood as "to official end  (something, such as a law)" or "to officially stop  (something, such as a law)."

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, separating alternative parts of a definition instead of alternative (but related) definitions. I'll revise my answer - sorry for the confusion!